# POCO support in ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, ado.net, poco

I want to manually map my Entity Classes(POCO) to the Database tables usin ADO.NET Entity framework using the XML mapping file. Is it possible to do so, as I have heard there is no POCO support in ADO.NET Entity Framework for VS2008( AM I Right?).....I want to use POCO classes in my project ad use the entity framework as an ORM.

Comment: much better POCO support in EF 2.0 (4.0)

Comment: You can project onto POCOs even in EF 1. Without knowing what your goal is, it's hard to say if this would be a good solution. Put some more effort into your question, and you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about EF 1.0 then you should use [IPOCO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738631.aspx) interfaces - a pseudo *POCO* implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [poco adapter on code.msdn.com.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter) not sure how good it is.